# Use React APP as a widget in an existing application

Tags: reactjs, webpack, drupal-8

I don't have a lot of experience with ReactJs and javascript packages.
I want to include React app https://getaroom.io/ into our existing Drupal 8 application as a widget. I know that I have to create a bundle. I tried to generate bundle using webpack.

Contents of webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
entry: './source/js/main.js',
output: {filename: 'bundle.js'} 
}
```

And after that I included generated bundle into Drupal:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="my_module_path/js/bundle.js?v=1.x"></script>
```

And I get following error in console: Error: Cannot find module "react"  bundle.js:74:47
Any help is appreciated. Thanks